# Script not returning display

Tags: html, csv, d3.js

Probably made a stupid error, but I can't get the following script to work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
d3.csv("Temperature.csv").then(function(data){
        console.log(data);

        let svgContainer = d3.select("myDiv").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 800);

        let myRectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data);

        myRectangle.enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d,i){
                    return 50 + (i*21);
                })
                .attr("y", 50)
                .attr("width",20)
                .attr("height", function(d){
                    return d.Temp * 10;
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d){
                    if (d.Temp <= 10) {return "blue";}
                    else if (d.Temp <=15) {return "green";}
                    else {return "red";}
                });
})
</script>
```

I'm running it through localhost:8000 (Python Web Server running in background), and the CSV file is a a list of 12 months, and random temperatures.

When the script runs, through the localhost (Google Chrome), there are no errors caught, however, it doesn't display any images (it is meant to show a histogram of sorts).

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of your `body` tag. Just below the `div`.

Comment: It's not `d3.select("myDiv")`, but `d3.select("#myDiv")` instead (`myDiv` is an ID).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado worked perfectly. Put this in an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Clauric Thank you, but this is a typo: we should not answer typo questions on S.O.